# How to adjust the width of the toastr message in Angular

Tags: angular, angular9, toastr, angular-toastr, ngx-toastr

I have toastr message notification using ngx-toastr from npm (my current stack is Angular 9)

Is there a way to alter the max-width for the messages since it is causing the message-text to wrap.

```
this.toastrService.error(
          'This is an error message to be displayed<br> please log back','',
          { enableHtml: true }
        ).
```

[image]

I want the **displayed** also to be in the first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the native classes, i.E.  `toast-top-full-width` or `toast-bottom-full-width`

```
 <toaster-container toaster-options="{
   'time-out': 2500, 
   'close-button':false, 
   'position-class':'toast-bottom-full-width'
  }"></toaster-container>
```

As an alternative you could also apply your custom class via `position-class` and define the class in your CSS.

```
 <toaster-container toaster-options="{
    'time-out': 2500, 
    'close-button':false, 
    'position-class':'my-own-toastr-class'
  }"></toaster-container>
```

CSS:

```
.my-own-toastr-class {
   width: 100%;
}
```

**Update** after clarifications from the comments:

From the docs:

> Setting Individual Options
>
> `success`, `error`, `info`, `warning` take (message, title, ToastConfig) pass an options object to replace any default option.

Example:

```
this.toastrService.error('everything is broken', 'Major Error', {
  timeOut: 3000,
});
```

So in your case for example that would be :

```
this.toastrService.error(
          'This is an error message to be displayed<br> please log back','',
          { enableHtml: true,
            position-class:'toast-bottom-full-width' 
          }
        ).
```

Or with your own custom class:

```
this.toastrService.error(
          'This is an error message to be displayed<br> please log back','',
          { enableHtml: true,
            position-class:'my-own-toastr-class' 
          }
        ).
```

Please see more info under OPTIONS at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr.

Comment: I don't have an <toaster-container> anywhere in my app.I have downloaded ngx-toastr from the npm and I'm just using the typescript code with inbuilt methods for showing notifications

Comment: @VigneshRavichandran Maybe you want to include that fact and the actual code where you invoke toastr in your question so people don't have to guess.. Anyway, you can still instantiate the toaster via the toaster-options in your .ts file.

Comment: I have updated the question for better understanding

Comment: and I think the position class has to be added at the root module